# Too many connect from unknown postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, reverse-dns

I am trying to set up an incoming email server by using postfix as MTA the issue I am facing is that there are too many 'connect from unknown' lines in the log. Can anyone help can I debug this issue? I think they might be due to the fact that my server is not giving enough time to remote client DNS to respond to the ptr query. I manually did reverse dns search using dig and was able to find the domain while the postfix server showed them unknown.

Comment: Well, *did* you lookup the names yourself, to distinguish resolver problems from the remote simply not publishing such record? I don't think postfix distinguishes these cases in logs.

Comment: I actually did tried digging the ip (from the same server) and I was able to get their domain while postfix for some reason showed unknown so I stumbled on this conclusion.

Comment: could be a problem with some resolv.conf or nss.conf setting whichever resolver postfix is using.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal on the internet, if it's the same ip which is doing a lot of connects, you can automatically ban them using fail2ban and a jail for postfix